# Tuple indexing in macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I'm trying to index data tuple in macro that generate signature for trait implementation, but have some errors. Can I index tuple or need another solution? Hack with `tuple_index` I found in google but it not works for me.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d4bc0f56c643cf4693279a9bd9db973

```
macro_rules! expr { ($x:expr) => ($x) } // HACK
macro_rules! tuple_index {
    ($tuple:expr, $idx:tt) => { expr!($tuple.$idx) }
}
macro_rules! gen_packer {
    (@step $data: expr, $_idx:expr,) => {};

    (@step $data: expr, $idx:expr, $T:ident, $($tail:ident,)*) => {
        // out.append(&mut $T::pack(tuple_index!(data,$idx)));
        tuple_index!($data, $idx);

        gen_packer!(@step $data, $idx + 1, $($tail,)*);
    };

    ($($T:ident),*) => {
        impl<$($T,)+> Packer<($($T,)+)> for Iproto
        where $($T: Pack<$T>,)+
        {
            fn pack(self, data: ($($T,)+)) -> Vec<u8> {
                let mut out = vec![];
                gen_packer!(@step data, 0, $($T,)*);
                return out
            }
        }
    }
}

gen_packer!(A);
```

Errors on compilation:

```
error: unexpected token: `0`
--> src/lib/iproto.rs:70:29
   |
70 |         tuple_index!($data, $idx);
   |                             ^^^^
...
99 | gen_packer!(A);
   | --------------- in this macro invocation

error: unexpected token: `,`
  --> src/lib/iproto.rs:63:46
   |
63 |     ($tuple:expr, $idx:tt) => { expr!($tuple.$idx) }
   |                                              ^
...
99 | gen_packer!(A);
   | --------------- in this macro invocation

error: no rules expected the token `0`
  --> src/lib/iproto.rs:70:29
   |
61 | macro_rules! expr { ($x:expr) => ($x) } // HACK
   | ----------------- when calling this macro
...
70 |         tuple_index!($data, $idx);
   |                             ^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
...
99 | gen_packer!(A);
   | --------------- in this macro invocation

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Comment: Your code gives me no error. You may want to use that macro in a function. Please provide an example where we can reproduce that error you got in your code, e.g. on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org)

Comment: Btw: your code works... https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12df25696429d43c658d5a9db38eb072
You may want to be more specific about what works and what doesn't. That's why it is important to provide an example that fully works/doesn't work. Only in that case we can help you

Comment: @hellow need to call gen_packer, not tuple_index. I'm update code

Comment: @AlexanderKudzin what is `A`?

Comment: @hellow letter for generic (not variable)

Comment: To *me* your code does not make sense at all. What you do want to achieve? It looks like you ran into a problem and overcomplicating it.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d4bc0f56c643cf4693279a9bd9db973 i'm add here all that need for receive this errors

Comment: I want to generate implementation of trait for tuple with various sizes

Comment: @hellow do you understand what I want?

Comment: Sadly not :/ but there are more people than me on SO ^^

Comment: What is the `Pack` trait here?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I index tuple or need another solution?

No. The expression `$idx + 1` will produce distinct tokens, for example `0`, `+`, `1`, and there is no way to evaluate that to a single literal token within a declarative macro.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with declarative macros. However, that's an easy job for procedural macros.

Here's a library to help with this specific use case: https://github.com/bkchr/impl-trait-for-tuples

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`typle`](https://crates.io/crates/typle) crate:

```rust
#[typle(Tuple for 0..=12)]
impl<T> Packer<T> for Iproto
where
    T: Tuple,
    typle_bound!(i in .. => T<{i}>): Pack<T<{i}>>,
{
    fn pack(self, data: T) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut out = Vec::new();
        for typle_index!(i) in 0..T::LEN {
            out.append(&mut T::<{i}>::pack(data[[i]]));
        }
        out
    }
}
```

This generates code equivalent to the following for 0..12 components:

```
impl<T0, T1> Packer<(T0, T1)> for Iproto
where
    T0: Pack<T0>,
    T1: Pack<T1>,
{
    fn pack(self, data: (T0, T1)) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut out = Vec::new();
        out.append(&mut <T0>::pack(data.0));
        out.append(&mut <T1>::pack(data.1));
        out
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @PeterHall correctly explained why your approach can't work. But there is a way to do that with declarative macros.

The trick is to use destructuring. There are two ways to access tuple elements: one is field access, like you tried. But then you face the problem that you cannot generate the indices. The only way to solve that with only declarative macros is to pass the indices, just like you pass the generic parameter names.

But there is another way: destructuring. And here we just need names to destructure into, not numbers. And we already have names: the generic parameters. We can just reuse them.

```rust
macro_rules! gen_packer {
    ($($T:ident),+) => {
        impl<$($T,)+> Packer<($($T,)+)> for Iproto
        where $(Iproto: Packer<$T>,)+
        {
            fn pack(&mut self, data: ($($T,)+)) -> Vec<u8> {
                #[allow(non_snake_case)]
                let ( $($T,)+ ) = data;
                let mut out = vec![];
                $(
                    out.append(&mut self.pack($T));
                )*
                out
            }
        }
    }
}


pub struct Iproto { }
pub trait Packer<T> {
    fn pack(&mut self, arg: T) -> Vec<u8>;
}

gen_packer!(A);
gen_packer!(A, B);
// ...
```

We can use another neat trick to save us the need to have multiple calls to our macros, by calling it from itself recursively with less parameters:

```rust
macro_rules! gen_packer {
    () => {
        impl Packer<()> for Iproto {
            fn pack(&mut self, _data: ()) -> Vec<u8> {
                vec![]
            }
        }
    };
    
    ($first:ident $(, $rest:ident)*) => {
        impl<$first $(, $rest)*> Packer<($first, $($rest,)*)> for Iproto
        where
            Iproto: Packer<$first>,
            $(Iproto: Packer<$rest>,)*
        {
            fn pack(&mut self, data: ($first, $($rest,)*)) -> Vec<u8> {
                #[allow(non_snake_case)]
                let ( $first, $($rest,)* ) = data;
                let mut out = vec![];
                out.append(&mut self.pack($first));
                $(
                    out.append(&mut self.pack($rest));
                )*
                out
            }
        }
        
        gen_packer!($($rest),*);
    };
}


pub struct Iproto { }
pub trait Packer<T> {
    fn pack(&mut self, arg: T) -> Vec<u8>;
}

gen_packer!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K);
```